# ScrollView making performance very slow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, syncfusion

I have a Xamarin forms project targeting Android 10.0.

I'm using a SyncFusion SfDataGrid to display information.

Inside each row of the DataGrid I have an entry field.

I encapsulated the DataGrid in a ScrollView so that when the user taps inside one of the entry fields the keyboard doesn't cover the screen.

The issue is when I add the ScrollView the page takes significantly longer to load. When I remove the ScrollView it is very snappy but focusing in an entry control that is on one of the bottom rows cause the keyboard to cover said row.

Why is the addition of a ScrollView causing these performance issues?

```xml
<Frame Padding="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="5" HasShadow="True">
    <ScrollView>
        <datagrid:SfDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <datagrid:SfDataGrid.GridStyle>
                <datagrid:DefaultStyle GridLinesVisibility="None"/>
            </datagrid:SfDataGrid.GridStyle>
            <datagrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                <datagrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Desc"  MappingName="Description"/>
                <datagrid:GridTemplateColumn MappingName="Qty">
                    <datagrid:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Entry Text="{Binding Qty}" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </datagrid:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>              
                </datagrid:GridTemplateColumn>           
            </datagrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>
        </datagrid:SfDataGrid>
    </ScrollView>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Isn't SfDataGrod already a scrolling View? Do you need to wrap it in a ScrollView manually? All the examples in their documentation indicate that you don't need to provide your own ScrollView.

Comment: Nesting scrollable views is discouraged for performance reasons: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes, but if you have an entry control in the SfDataGrid, as I do, it won't readjust the screen to compensate for the keyboard popping up - this is achieved by wrapping the grid in a scrollview, which is resulting in performance issues for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're nesting a scrollable View (SfDataGrid) inside a [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview) which is discouraged (see link).

You should remove the ScrollView and instead specify a [Soft Keyboard Input Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode), e.g. using the `Pan` or `Resize` value, if you want to make sure that the keyboard doesn't hide the focused `Entry`.

Add the following to your App.xaml.cs:

```xml
<Application
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
</Application>
```

Alternatively, you can also set the `WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` somewhere in your App's code-behind:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;

//...

App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Note that this will work on Android only.

Comment: This is what I have currently Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize). If I remove that it doesn't hide the row anymore but I lose the title information. The datagrid in the scrollview is exactly how I want it to work, but without the performance issues. Is there a mode I can set to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "I lose the title information"? You could try `AdjustPan`, but that will move everything up.

Comment: Resize is the mode I already had it set to, which resulted in the keyboard hiding the row without the inclusion of a scrollview. When I remove that line of code that specifies resize mode it no longer hides the row but pushes everything up, including the page title and buttons above the data grid

Answer (score 1):

SfDatagrid basically uses virtualization concept behind the screen, which means it only has less number of actual rows (Visual Element) based on SfDataGrid Height (view port height) and position of the rows will be altered based on scrolling position. That's how it has the excellent scrolling and loading performance irrespective of the itemsource collection size. But When you put SfDataGrid inside scrollview, basically scrollview will measure SfDataGrid and set its height based on the content size (ItemSource collection size) which will break virtualization and result in creating all row element based on itemsource collection size.

If you wish to use SfDataGrid inside the scrollview, assign some desired height to SfDataGrid using HeightRequest property.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

P.S : Ex Team lead of SfDataGrid